# CakePHP how to get the running total in an entity using a virtual field?

Tags: cakephp, cumulative-sum, cakephp-4.x

I have field called deposit, I am trying to create a virtual field called balance. Below my desire output, It's like chaining sum.

```
deposit   balance   
100       100
300       400
10        410
```

I have tried below code in entity

```
public $balance = 0;
protected function _getBalance()
{
    $this->balance = $this->balance + $this->deposit;
    return $this->balance;
}
```

I have got all `0` in balance.

I am getting result like below

```
deposit   balance   
    100       0
    300       0
    10        0
```

How can I get desire result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An entity has no idea about other entities, but that would be required in order for it to be able to sum up the balance.

The two solutions that come to my mind here are a) iterating over all the results and modifying the data, or b) in case your DBMS supports them, using window functions to create the running total on SQL level.

If you iterate over all results you can access the previous result's balance and calculate the sum and populate the `balance` field accordingly, for example in a result formatter:

```php
$query->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
    $previous = null;
    return $results->map(function ($row) use (&$previous) {
        if ($previous === null) {
            $row['balance'] = $row['deposit'];
        } else {
            $row['balance'] = $previous['balance'] + $row['deposit'];
        }
        
        $previous = $row;
        
        return $row;
    });
});
```

On SQL level window functions would allow you sum up previous rows:

```php
$query->select(function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
    return [
        'deposit',
        'balance' => $query
            ->func()
            ->sum('deposit')
            ->over()
            ->order('id')
            ->rows(null)
    ];
});
```

This would create a `SELECT` clause like this:

```sql
SELECT
    deposit,
    (
        SUM(deposit) OVER (
            ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        )
    ) AS balance
```

where the sum is calculated over all previous rows up to and including the current row.

It should be noted that window functions on the builder are only supported as of CakePHP 4.1, in previous version you'd have to create custom expressions or pass raw SQL:

```php
$query->select([
    'deposit',
    'balance' => 'SUM(deposit) OVER (
        ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    )'
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Adding Calculated Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-calculated-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Window Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#window-functions)**